# How to add multiple segments to a Google Analytics API report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

How can I add multiple segments to a report using the Google Analytics API plugin for Google Sheets?

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible currently.
The Google Analytics API plugin for sheets currently uses the [Analytics Core Reporting API V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). [Multiple segments](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics#segments) was added with [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.segments).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the API version, this either IS or IS NOT possible.

v3 doesn't support multiple segments, you would have to make a dedicated request for each segment.

v4 **does** support multiple segments, I've used it within R with this package: http://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/ . Name the segments before submitting the API.